# java.lang.IllegalStateException while parsing Json string response using Gson()

Tags: java, json, gson, google-places-api

I am working with Google Places API to get information about a place `findplacefromtext` endpoint. Here is the code I am working with to make the request

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum of Contemporary Art Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,rating&key=API_KEY")
        .method("GET", null)
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Above code does print correct response which looks like:

```json
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "140 George St, The Rocks NSW 2000, Australia",
         "name" : "Museum of Contemporary Art Australia",
         "rating" : 4.4
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I want to parse this response and put it into an object which I can utilize later, so I decided to use Gson for it.

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    CandidateResponseTest responseMapper = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), CandidateResponseTest.class);
    List<Candidate> listResult = responseMapper.getCandidates();
    for (Candidate r : listResult) {
        System.out.println("Fetched name: " + r.getName());
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This piece of code is throwing `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception where on the line that has `gson.fromJson`. From the print statement result shown above, I know that `response.body().string` is not empty.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.select(RealBufferedSource.kt:218)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.readBomAsCharset(Util.kt:258)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.kt:187)
    at org.example.PlaceSearch.getPlaceTest(PlaceSearch.java:61)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:15)
```

This is how `candidateResponse` looks:

```java
public class CandidateResponseTest {

    @SerializedName("candidates")
    private List<Candidate> candidates;

    public List<Candidate> getCandidates(){
        return this.candidates;
    }
}
```

and this is how `Candidate` looks:

```java
public class Candidate{
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @SerializedName("formatted_address")
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    @SerializedName("rating")
    private String rating;


}
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but I notice that rating isn't a string, and that status is missing.

Comment: I added ```status``` and changed ```rating``` to be a Double but still seeing same error.

Comment: @tgdavies added full stack trace

Comment: If you look at the stack trace you'll see it is nothing to do with the JSON parsing, but a problem reading the body of the response.

Comment: @tgdavies but I am able to use response.body().string() to print response in previous step. Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html "Because this class does not buffer the full response in memory, the application may not re-read the bytes of the response. "

Comment: Removing previous response.body().toString() helped resolve this!